# jQuery smooth scroll doesn't work on iPad and iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, ipad

I used a jquery smooth scroll effect, nothing fancy..just jQuery...and it doesn't seem to work iPad or iPhone or any other tablets..the url is here: http://teothemes.com/wp/viewpoint/

and this is the code I used for jquery smooth scroll:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("a[href*=#]").on('click', function() {
  if(parseInt(jQuery(this.hash).offset().top) !== parseInt(jQuery(window).scrollTop()))
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top}, 1500);
});
```

});

If there's anyone that has any idea, it's highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out the CSS Property -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;?

Answer (score 0):

I've read this is an iOS 6.1 issue, and it doesn't appear to be fixed in the earliest version of iOS 7. Don't really have a solid uncomplicated solution, so as a workaround, I'm using [Gentle Anchors](http://www.angelwatt.com/coding/gentle_anchors.php) when iPhones and iPods are detected, and will update this post if I find I need it for other devices.

```
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top }, 1000);
    if( /iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        Gentle_Anchors.Setup(target);
        //for iPhone & iPod 
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm seeing some stuttering unless I tell the page to set the viewport equal to the iPhone's portrait width in the `<head>` if one of these devices has been detected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.nav-wrapper ul li a').click(function(e) { 
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top-134}, 500);
});
```